# dc.bar-chart margin and axis label size adjustment

Tags: css, d3.js, dc.js

I found my yAxis label too big to be shown--it was truncated by the left border.

I tried increasing the left margin, with no success. It seems that the label text is left-aligned. So increasing the margin only gets the label further away from the ticks text.

Please see the attached screenshots. The one with wider gap is [margin.left=70](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_pl4WL362gPZ2djTnBIS0ktazA/view?usp=sharing). The other one is with [margin.left=40](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_pl4WL362gPZFJlV3FqYk9neW8/view?usp=sharing). No matter which case, the 'Expenditures' seems to be truncated on the left side.

Is there anywhere in the dc.css that I can change this configuration?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust where the axis labels are placed relative to the edge by using the second parameter when you call the `.xAxisLabel()` and `.yAxisLabel()` methods. This sets the "padding" (actually the offset from the left/bottom).

[coordinateGridMixin.xAxisLabel docs](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+xAxisLabel)

[coordinateGridMixin.yAxisLabel docs](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+yAxisLabel)

It's confusing that the text size gets set through the stylesheet but the positioning can't be. I'm not sure if there's any way around this, though

Comment: @Gordon :- I am facing the similar problem. i have a chart and i want to position my x-axis title with more margin than default in respect to the x-axis label. I need to find a way around. 
This is the piece of code i am using:- 
.xAxisLabel(xaxisModel,5) // second parameter doesn't affect the title position at all